# How to correctly use the Collada exporter?

Tags: animation, mesh, export

I finally managed to finish creating a complete character in Blender and i wanted to export it for the Godot game engine, so i wanted to use Collada (i tried both the Blender default exporter and the better Collada exporter from the Godot website) as my exporting format but when i tried to export i stumbled upon some weird errors that i couldn't really find an answer on google. Here is an image with the errors i'm getting : [image: Errors]

I imported the .dae file into the Godot engine to see if it has any problems and the shirt of the character is invisible but only the front side and when i play the idle animation the hands deform weirdly.

I would appreciate if you guys could help me with this or tell me what i should search to fix and avoid these errors in the future.

Comment: I managed to fix it, apparently i had to check the apply modifiers box when exporting, well i still have problems regarding the animations tho, the rig and the mesh act separately in the engine which is weird since i parented them, they are exported as two different items. Here is a picture with the current problem : https://i.imgur.com/wo29EUl.png

Answer (score 1):

Try applying scale, rotation and location(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) on the rig and then the mesh, while in *Object Mode*.

You'll have to redo the animation